# SOLR 4.1 throws: Unknown commit parameter 'waitFlush'?

Tags: magento, solr, tomcat7

I'm running Magento EE 1.11 and I've deployed SOLR 4.1 with tomcat7. I've copied solrconfig.xml and schema.xml provided by Magento and fixed all the issues SOLR was having with the two files because they were intended for SOLR 3.6 and properly configured Magento.

Now, when I reindex search in Magneto at the very last moment SOLR spits out this exception:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unknown commit parameter 'waitFlush'
```

and Magento reverts back to saying a search re-indexing is required. Has anyone ran into this problem? From all the googling I've done there seems to be a patch for this, but where and how do I apply it?

Comment: Resolved my issue here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/php-solr-client/_KX_J6vW2b8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really use SOLR 3.x rather than 4 with Magento EE.

Here's a walk-through for configuration and installation.

### On Debian/Ubuntu

The most straightforward installation is pretty easy using `tomcat` and your package manager. The dependencies will be met automatically.

```
apt-get install tomcat6
```

### On CentOS/RedHat

You need to grab some alternative repo's to make this possible

Eg.

```
rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uhv http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/x86_64/rpmforge/RPMS/rpmforge-release-0.3.6-1.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm
rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
```

Then you can install the package from `yum`

```
yum install yum-priorities ant tomcat6 tomcat6-admin

cd /usr/src/
mkdir sun-java
cd sun-java
```

Now it gets a little trickier. Sun used to permit direct downloads; but they now have a stupid session validation in place - so download the binary via your PC and upload it to the machine.

You need both the Linux JDK and JRE.

The commands would have been:

```
wget -O jdk.rpm.bin http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u29-b11/jdk-6u29-linux-x64-rpm.bin
wget -O jre.rpm.bin http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u29-b11/jre-6u29-linux-x64-rpm.bin
```

You can alternatively use OpenJDK

```
wget http://jpackage.org/jpackage50.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jpackage50.repo
yum install -y java-1.6.0-openjdk
```

Once you've uploaded the binaries

```
chmod +x *.bin
./jre.rpm.bin
./jdk.rpm.bin
ln -s /var/lib/tomcat6 /usr/share/tomcat6
```

### Then the remaining steps

Then drop in your respective selection of `solr`

```
mkdir /usr/src/solr
cd /usr/src/solr
wget http://mirrors.ukfast.co.uk/sites/ftp.apache.org/lucene/solr/3.6.1/apache-solr-3.6.1.tgz
tar xvfz apache-solr-3.6.1.tgz
cd apache-solr-3.6.1
cp dist/apache-solr-*.war /var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/solr.war
mkdir -p /var/lib/tomcat6/solr
```

Then add the Magento `solr` configuration

```
INSTALL_DIR="/var/lib/tomcat6/solr"
touch $INSTALL_DIR/solr.xml
CORES=( "staging" "development" "live" )
for CORE in "${CORES[@]}"; do
  mkdir -p $INSTALL_DIR/$CORE/conf $INSTALL_DIR/$CORE/data 
  cp -par /usr/src/solr/apache-solr-3.6.1/example/solr/conf/* $INSTALL_DIR/$CORE/conf
  cp -par /home/path/public_html/lib/Apache/Solr/Conf/* $INSTALL_DIR/$CORE/conf
done
```

Then set up the cores

```
cat > /var/lib/tomcat6/solr/solr.xml << EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<solr persistent="true" sharedLib="lib">
  <cores adminPath="/admin/cores">
    <core name="staging" instanceDir="staging" config="solrconfig.xml" schema="schema.xml" />
    <core name="development" instanceDir="development" config="solrconfig.xml" schema="schema.xml" />
    <core name="live" instanceDir="live" config="solrconfig.xml" schema="schema.xml" />
  </cores>
</solr>
EOF
```

Then finally, clean up permissions and restart `solr`

```
chown -R tomcat6:tomcat6 /var/lib/tomcat6/solr
/etc/init.d/tomcat6 restart
```

Then in Magento, you've now got 3 possible independent cores you can use for your store environments.

- `staging/solr`
- `development/solr`
- `live/solr`

*Attribution: http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/multiple-solr-cores-for-magento-on-debianubuntucentosredhat/*

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer - yes, I skimmed over the instructions and didn't see the requirement about 3.6.2 -- everything worked fine after installing the correct version..